# Cannot create BOOL from object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.5

I am following the guide cocoa programming for mac os x, 4th edition.In the 32th chapter I messed up the code, and I didn't backup it, so I had to download the solutions from big nerd ranch.
The project is about core data relashionships, there is a class Employee and a class Department.

Employee.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Department;

@interface Employee : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * firstName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * lastName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Department *department;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *fullName;

@end
```

Employee.m :

```
#import "Employee.h"
#import "Department.h"


@implementation Employee

@dynamic firstName;
@dynamic lastName;
@dynamic department;

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingFullName
{
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"firstName", @"lastName", nil];
}

- (NSString *)fullName
{
    NSString *first = [self firstName];
    NSString *last = [self lastName];
    if (!first)
        return last;
    if (!last)
        return first;
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", first, last];
}

@end
```

Department.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Department : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * deptName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *employees;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *manager;
@end

@interface Department (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addEmployeesObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)removeEmployeesObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)addEmployees:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeEmployees:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Department.m :

```
#import "Department.h"
#import "Employee.h"

@implementation Department

@dynamic deptName;
@dynamic employees;
@dynamic manager;

- (void)addEmployeesObject:(Employee *)value
{
    NSLog(@"Dept %@ adding employee %@",
          [self deptName], [value fullName]);
    NSSet *s = [NSSet setWithObject:value];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"employees"
                withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation
                   usingObjects:s];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"employees"] addObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"employees"
               withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation
                  usingObjects:s];
}

- (void)removeEmployeesObject:(Employee *)value
{
    NSLog(@"Dept %@ removing employee %@",
          [self deptName], [value fullName]);
    Employee *manager = (Employee *)[self manager];
    if (manager == value) {
        [self setManager:nil];
    }
    NSSet *s = [NSSet setWithObject:value];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"employees"
                withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation
                   usingObjects:s];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"employees"] removeObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"employees"
               withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation
                  usingObjects:s];
}


@end
```

I have those core data relashionships and entities:

[image: Department]

[image: Employee]

I also use some array controllers to bind the core data values to some outlets.
The full project can be found [here](http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/cocoa_programming_for_mac_os_x_th_edition_)., 32th chapter (it's identical to mine) in "download solutions".
Tell me if you need more code to understand this error:

```
2012-10-31 15:27:43.977 Departments[1229:303] Cannot create BOOL from object (
) of class _NSControllerArrayProxy
2012-10-31 15:27:43.989 Departments[1229:303] Cannot create BOOL from object (
) of class _NSControllerArrayProxy
```

Seems like posting a whole project is not recommended, but I could do so if you say it's ok.

PS: I' using the code downloaded from solutions, it's the same but it doesn't work, maybe because I have a higher version of xcode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like a bindings issue. You probably have an "enabled" or "hidden" binding (which takes a BOOL) linked up with a property that cannot be converted to BOOL.

Comment: I still can't find the problem, the only connections made with a method that returns a BOOL are connected with the canRemove method of an array controller.How do I post the xib files?

Comment: Maybe it helps to know that the NSControllerArrayProxy object is often the contentArray of an NSArrayController.

Comment: Here are some bindings:Depts array controller' managed object context is bound with file owner, model key path managedObjectContext.ManagerPopUp's content set is bound with Depts selection.employees; EmployeeList array controller'scontent set is bound with Depts selections.employees;

Comment: Nothing to do, it was all right, I just had to make a clean build and delete the project folder in derived data.